# Single and Double round robin Combination

Tags: combinatorics

IPL tournament has 10 teams. Each team plays 2 matches with 6 teams and 1 match with remaining three teams. This happens such that each team plays with every other team atleast once.  Top 4 team are to be selected. what could be the maximum number of matches that are won by a team that failed to qualify? For each win +2, for loss no points and for tie +1.

Comment: Are draws possible ? and what is the scoring system ?

Comment: yes draw is allowed

Answer (score 0):

Each team plays $15$ matches.  We can initially ignore the two games against the same team and imagine a tournament of $16$ teams.  If we get a five way tie at the top one of the five will fail to qualify.  If all of those five beat the other eleven teams and get four points against the other four they all get $26$ points.  That would say a team can win $13$ matches and fail to qualify.

To translate this to our IPL tournament we would have to be able to find five teams that only play each other once.  As each team only plays three others once each that is not possible.  The best we can do is have five teams that play three of the others once and one of the others twice.  I am sure this is possible but would bet the tournament is not structured that way.  In this case each of the five wins a maximum of $12$ games with one draw.